# Htaccess rules get overriden

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want my .htaccess in the web server's root dir to redirect any request starting with `^assets/(.*)$` to the folder `public/$1`. All other requests have to go to `index.php?request=$1`. I also want to keep get parameters (L flag does it) in this case.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^assets/(.*)$ public/$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^(?!assets)(.*)$ index.php?request=$1 [L,QSA]
```

The only problem is that the last line overrides the previous :/
I also tested with `(.*)` but without success.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule "^/assets/(.*)$" "/public/$1" [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "!^/assets/"
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "!^/index.php"
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "!^/public"
RewriteRule (.*) "/index.php?request=$1" [L,QSA]
```

- `QSA`: appends the parameters to the rewritten part
- `L`: last.  Which means if it matches, do not process any other rewrite.
- Rewrites start at `/`
- To apply a condition on a RewriteRule, use RewriteCond

References:
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html 
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

The first rule says:

- if it starts with "/assets/", anything following the second `/` will be rewritten as "/public/$1".

The RewriteCond and RewriteRule says:

- if it does not start by "/assets/", take whatever you received, add it at the end of "/index.php?request=".
  So `http://www.example.com/directory/somepage.html` will go to 
   `http://www.example.com/index.php?request=/directory/somepage.html`.
- If there are parameters in the request, they are appended at the end like so:
  `http://www.example.com/directory/somepage.html?a=1&b=4` will go to 
  `http://www.example.com/index.php?request=/directory/somepage.html?a=1&b=4`

**EDIT Nov 19 1115**

Added a second RewriteCond to make sure "/index.php" does not rewrite to itself.  And a third, in case you want "/public" to also not redirect to "/index.php".

Comment: Doesn't work, I'm getting a 500 error due to missconfiguration. That's not related to php because that's working properly with my version even if it isnt what I want.

Comment: Give more details than that please.  What URL have you tried?  Which ones do not work?  Put `print_r($GET);` in your index.php to see what you received, what logs do you get in Apache?  I cannot guess.

Comment: This is the error your script gives me in any case `AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.` However, mine writes correctly the $_GET array with request matching this part of the url : https://any.com/**any/any/any?a=1&b=2** and the right other get params as *a* and *b*. The only problem is that it never redirects if the url starts by assets because the last line overwrites the previous.

Comment: Ok I figured it out, sorry.  I added a second RewriteCond to avoid "/index.php" to rewrite onto itself.  What about "/public"?  Should be go to "index.php" or not?  I modified the asnwer in case you need that.

Comment: I don't care about /public the most important is that the rest work. I think it would be nice not to rewrite when public is called.

Comment: Finally, the redirection to assets doesn't work, I everytime get 404 err. I guess Chrome's cache was displaying me the image :/

Comment: It would be nice if you posted the log entry, the exact URL you are typing.

Comment: This should go to `http://example.com/public/img/favicon.png` with the rules I answered.  Does that file exist?

Comment: Indeed, it does :c